# how to create activity indicator for blackberry 5.0.0?

Tags: blackberry-os-v5

I am trying to prepare activity indicator for BLACKBERRY 5.0.0,but getting failed into it..
I am trying to create two thread classes, one with background functionality and one with activity indicator class which extends popup screen...but getting an error as "too many thread error...

please help me out

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur because blackberry supports only 63 threads. It gives "Too many thread exception", if count of threads exceeds by 63.

So try to use **UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable{})** for activity indicator. This will help to resolve the issue.